# WPF - Error inserting VisualBrush into a Style?

Tags: wpf, path, styles, resourcedictionary, visualbrush

I need to keep all my paths in a canvas so I can retrieve them easily. I found out that it works with `VisualBrush`. When I try to retrieve the `VisuahBrush` and put in into `Style`s, it has error:

Object of the type `System.Windows.Media.VisualBrush` cannot be applied to a property that expects the type `Systems.Windows.Style`.

How else can I keep all my paths in a canvas and still retrievable in `Style`s?

Any ideas will be a great help, thanks!

```
<VisualBrush x:Key="myVisualBrush">
    <VisualBrush.Visual>
        <Canvas>
            <Path Fill="#FF231F20" Stretch="Fill" Width="12.69" Height="14.477" Canvas.Left="652.196" Canvas.Top="88.61" Data="F1M617.2051,52.7275C616.7281,52.4525,616.3391,52.6775,616.3391,53.2275L616.3391,66.4695C616.3391,67.0195,616.7281,67.2445,617.2051,66.9695L628.6721,60.3485C629.1481,60.0735,629.1481,59.6235,628.6721,59.3485z"/>
        </Canvas>
    </VisualBrush.Visual>
</VisualBrush>

<Style x:Key="myVisualStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource myVisualBrush}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <!-- Styles -->
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your VisualBrush is designed to be assigned to an object that accepts a Brush, like a Background not a Style like you are attempting to. I would suggest that you do some thing like this.(*This example will assign the same `VisualBrush` to every `TextBox` if you need to be able to pick and choose your brushes then I would suggest that you add back the `x:Key` to your style and assign the Styles individually to your TextBox's*)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="400">
    <Window.Resources>
        <VisualBrush x:Key="myVisualBrush">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Canvas>
                    <Path Fill="#FF231F20" Stretch="Fill" Width="12.69" Height="14.477" Canvas.Left="652.196" Canvas.Top="88.61" Data="F1M617.2051,52.7275C616.7281,52.4525,616.3391,52.6775,616.3391,53.2275L616.3391,66.4695C616.3391,67.0195,616.7281,67.2445,617.2051,66.9695L628.6721,60.3485C629.1481,60.0735,629.1481,59.6235,628.6721,59.3485z"/>
                </Canvas>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>

        <Style  TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource myVisualBrush}"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="myPathStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource myVisualBrush}"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox  x:Name="MyTextBox" />
        <Path Style="{StaticResource myPathStyle}"  x:Name="myPath" >
            <Path.Data>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="100,100,100,100"/>
            </Path.Data>        
        </Path>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your reply. Your example worked well, thanks for the explanation. When I change the `TargetType="{x:Type Path}` it says: Property 'background' was not found in type 'Path'. Can changing my Resources resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: @LilyT what are you trying to accomplish? Your example in your question was using a TextBox, which has a BackGround Property. If you are using Paths, you have a Fill Property but you need to assign it with a key otherwise you will get a stackoverlow because the brush has a path also. I will edit the example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wanted to try if I could reuse the resource to a different source. Your example helped me understand better. Thanks once again!